# Handling port conflicts

Tags: sockets, port

I would like to implement a peer to peer chat program as an exercise for me to learn a little bit of network programming. The way I understand this sort of application is usually implemented: is to make it act simultaneously as a TCP client and server: sending messages on the client side and recieving them on the server side.

So far whenever I wrote any kind of socket programming, I just chose some random high port number that I sticked to, but I am curious what are the standard ways to assure that a conflicting program isn't already listening on a specific port? Do you just send connection requests over some range until a connection is established and a port number is agreed on, or is there some smarter way of dealing with that?

Comment: One could identify a port range which is unlikely to be occupied for your service. For e.g., this is a good starting place (not exhaustive, BTW!): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers . But, even then that's not guaranteed. You'll still have to check whether your selected port is available prior to launching. Open the socket on that port if true; report / handle the occupied port to the user if false

Comment: @jrd1 This area is for comments, not answers to the question.

Comment: How does the program figure out the IP address? It can figure out the port number the same way

Comment: @Rob Thanks, Rob - I provided that comment as it didn't seem sufficient for an answer with the current context